# How to force recapture to only display text images as opposed to picture images

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, mvcrecaptcha

this site:https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?hl=en

states that there are two options: audio and image

Are these the only options? Because there seems to be example on the internet of just text recaptures like this:
http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html

so using this:

does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can't force google. It's servers randomly set whether images or text puzzle. See how to [break reCAPTCHA](http://scraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge/).